# Telerik (RadEditor) pop up box disappear in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik, popup

I am using a third party plugin Telerik RadEditor version 2011.01.0519.35. There suppose to be a popup that allows me to paste the content.
[image: Popup found in all other version of browsers except IE]

Popup found works ok in all other version of browsers but disappear in IEs except IE edge. The only message that I can found is the warning message from IE console:
[image]

Can someone point me out on what is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is very old and does not support modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, mobile browsers, anything above IE9). **You should upgrade to the latest**.

As for this concrete dialog - you may not need in edge, depending on what you are attempting to paste because if the browser handles pasting well and provides the needed flavors, you will not get these dialogs, as explained here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/pasting-content/overview

EDIT: Test the behavior of the control in the official demos to see the expected behavior:

- general setup: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx
- pasting from MS Word: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx